# Prophet forecasting time series model Dataframe 2 non-NaN rows Issues

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, prophet

I am trying to implement forecast model in my pyspark analytics and we are getting as below error. kindly help me where exactly, we may have to apply changes or fix the issue.

Error:

> PythonException: '**ValueError: Dataframe has less than 2 non-NaN rows.**',
> from , line 17. Full traceback below:
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task 0 in stage 367.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
> 0.3 in stage 367.0 (TID 541) (172.26.145.6 executor 0): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'ValueError: Dataframe
> has less than 2 non-NaN rows.', from , line
> 17. Full traceback below: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 17, in pd_apply_forecast   File
> "/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prophet/forecaster.py",
> line 1113, in fit
> raise ValueError('Dataframe has less than 2 non-NaN rows.') ValueError: Dataframe has less than 2 non-NaN rows.

My code :

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.pandas as ps
from prophet import Prophet

def run_row_outlier_check(df: DataFrame, min_date, start_date, groupby_cols, job_id) -> DataFrame:
    """
    |    Generate dataframe containing prophet model forecasting of row counts
    """
    pd_schema = StructType([
        StructField(groupby_col, StringType(), True),
        StructField("ds", DateType(), True),
        StructField("y", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("yhat", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("yhat_lower", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("yhat_upper", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("trend", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("trend_lower", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("trend_upper", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("additive_terms", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("additive_terms_lower", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("additive_terms_upper", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("weekly", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("weekly_lower", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("weekly_upper", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("yearly", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("yearly_lower", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("yearly_upper", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("multiplicative_terms", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("multiplicative_terms_lower", FloatType(), True),
        StructField("multiplicative_terms_upper", FloatType(), True)
        ])

    # dataframe of consecutive dates 
    df_rundates = (ps.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(start=min_date, end=(date.today() - timedelta(days=1)))})).to_spark()

    # combine + explode to create row for each date and grouped col (e.g. business segment)
    df_bizlist = (
        df.filter(f"{date_col} >= coalesce(date_sub(date 'today', {num_days_check}), '{start_date}')")
            .groupBy(groupby_col)
            .count()
            .orderBy(col("count").desc())
    )

    df_rundates_bus = (
        df_rundates
            .join(df_bizlist, how='full')
            .select(df_bizlist[groupby_col], df_rundates["date"].alias("ds"))
    )

    # create input dataframe for prophet forecast
    df_grouped_cnt = df.groupBy(groupby_cols).count()
    df_input = (
        df_rundates_bus.selectExpr(f"{groupby_col}", "to_date(ds) as ds")
            .join(df_grouped_cnt.selectExpr(f"{groupby_col}", f"{date_col} as ds", "count as y"), on=['ds',f'{groupby_col}'], how='left')
            .withColumn("y", coalesce("y", lit(0)))
            .repartition(sc.defaultParallelism, "ds")
    )
    # cache dataframe to improve performance
    # df_input.cache()
    #            .repartition(sc.defaultParallelism, "ds")
    
    # forecast
    df_forecast = (
        df_input
            .groupBy(groupby_col)
                .applyInPandas(pd_apply_forecast, schema=pd_schema)

    )
    # filter forecast with outlier scores
    df_rowoutliers = (
        df_forecast
            .filter("y > 0 AND (y > yhat_upper OR y < array_max(array(yhat_lower,0)))")
            .withColumn("check_type", lit("row_count"))
            .withColumn("deduct_score", expr("round(sqrt(pow(y-yhat, 2) / pow(yhat_lower - yhat_upper,2)))").cast('int'))
            .select(
                col("check_type"),
                col("ds").alias("ref_date"),
                col(groupby_col).alias("ref_dimension"),
                col("y").cast('int').alias("actual"),
                col("deduct_score"),
                col("yhat").alias("forecast"),
                col("yhat_lower").alias("forecast_lower"),
                col("yhat_upper").alias("forecast_upper")
            )
    )
    
    return add_metadata_columns(df_forecast, job_id), add_metadata_columns(df_rowoutliers, job_id)

def pd_apply_forecast(pd_history: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame: 
    # remove missing values and filter out null business segments
    pd_history = (pd_history[pd_history[groupby_col].notnull()]
                      .dropna())
    
    
    # instantiate the model, configure the parameters
    model = Prophet(
        growth='linear',
        yearly_seasonality='auto',  # default: auto
        weekly_seasonality='auto',  # default: auto
        daily_seasonality=False,    # default: auto
        seasonality_mode='additive'
    )
    
    # fit the model
    model.fit(pd_history)
    
    # configure predictions
    pd_future = model.make_future_dataframe(
        periods=365, 
        freq='d',
        include_history=True
    )
    
    # make predictions
    pd_forecast = model.predict(pd_future)
    
    # ASSEMBLE EXPECTED RESULT SET
    # --------------------------------------
    # get relevant fields from forecast
    pd_f = pd_forecast[ ['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper', 'trend', 'trend_lower', 'trend_upper', 'additive_terms', 'additive_terms_lower', 'additive_terms_upper', 'weekly', 'weekly_lower', 'weekly_upper', 'yearly', 'yearly_lower', 'yearly_upper', 'multiplicative_terms', 'multiplicative_terms_lower', 'multiplicative_terms_upper'] ].set_index('ds')

    # get relevant fields from history
    pd_h = pd_history[ ['ds', groupby_col, 'y'] ].set_index('ds')

    # join history and forecast
    pd_results = pd_f.join(pd_h, how='left')
    pd_results.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
    
    
    # filter out null dimensions
    pd_results = pd_results[pd_results[groupby_col].notnull()]
    
    # return predictions
    return pd_results[ [groupby_col, 'ds', 'y', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper', 'trend', 'trend_lower', 'trend_upper', 'additive_terms', 'additive_terms_lower', 'additive_terms_upper', 'weekly', 'weekly_lower', 'weekly_upper', 'yearly', 'yearly_lower', 'yearly_upper', 'multiplicative_terms', 'multiplicative_terms_lower', 'multiplicative_terms_upper'] ]
```

Comment: Dear All, please help us

Comment: Dear All,   I am expecting some one help. kindly do the needful help

Answer (score 0):

As message mentioned - you need to have at least two rows in the group in order to make a prediction. Remove rows with groups that have only one value.

Comment: could you please help me more specifically in my above i posted code

Comment: your code should be fine, check your df rows which groups have less than 2 rows

Comment: which df(dataframe) we would have to check, there is many df i have declared, can you please highlight the line number which you specific to check

Comment: I am trying below code before drop the or filter the row but not working

Comment: df_forecast = (
        df_input
            .groupBy(groupby_col)
                .applyInPandas(pd_apply_forecast, schema=pd_schema)

Comment: df_input = df_input.dropna(thresh=2)

Comment: PythonException: 'ValueError: Dataframe has less than 2 non-NaN rows.'